# How to setup node references

Tags: 7, nodes

im creating website for racing events, basically website have added all races that are happening during one year, and it stores data for previous races. I was asked to move from website from .net N2CMS to Drupal.

Im having problems with setting up proper content types and their references.

In the old website they have added several races. Every race node contains basic details ( town, country, best time, website url... ) and besides that details every race have data about previous years winners ( Name, Timings, Car ).

On the main race node there is this basic data and bellow that there are results from latest 5 years with ability to expand and show all previous years.

So its clear to me how to make main race content type and add fields, but i was wondering how to make it easy for admin to add winners of previous years, and this has to be modular as much as possible, because some races have this data all the way down to 1972, but yet some of them have just few years back.

So i guess some kind of node reference should be used here but just dont have it clear in my head what i need to do.

Sorry if my questions is not clear, i tried to explain it so that everyone can understand it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create two content types

- Race Details
- Race Standings

  - Node reference to Race Details as a field
  - Year
  - A [Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) with details (Fields) like

    - Race Winner Name
    - Timings
    - Car
    - Position etc

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it was not so hard as i thought.

I created 2 content types Race and Race details.

I installed [references](https://drupal.org/project/references) module and added a filed (node reference) called "Race" in node Race details.

Than i created new region and printed it below main content.

In next step i created a view with block and page, added all fields needed. And than using contextual filters ( Node id from url ) i printed block below main content.